# Sqlserver.Types issue when migrating from VS2010 Express to VS2013 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I have upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition to Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition. I am running into lots of problem during `Database Connection` and `DataSet` manipulation.

I have a `DataSet` table that must be implemented with two new fields according to new database table specification. When I am trying to add these two new fields, I get the following error:

> Cannot load file or assemblys 'Microsof.SqlServer.Types Version
>   11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of it's dependencies. Cannot find specified file.

I have previously used Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition (English) and now I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition (Italian)

Comment: How are you trying to add the fields?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I developed the external Database with MS Access (2003, 2007, 2010). The problem I'm facing raises when trying tu add fields via Datasource wizard in VS2013. Couldn't try anything elese. The application does not have any problem at runtime.

Comment: also noticed that if I try to add a new table from externa DB via DataSource wizard I get the following error "Cannot retrieve information about schema for the table <TABLE NAME>"